Restricting creation of subnet for particular vpc in AWS
I am creating role & want to give permission to create subnet but only inside particular VPC. My terraform code look like below
statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:CreateSubnet",
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEqualsIgnoreCase"
      variable = "ec2:VpcID"
      values   = ["vpc-xxxx64eeb9480xxxx"]
    }
  }

but it is not working. Giving authorization error. How can I restrict policy for particular VPC?

There's a small issue in your condition block. The condition block you're using is meant for S3 bucket policies, not for IAM policies related to EC2.
To restrict the subnet creation permission to a specific VPC, you should use the StringEquals condition for ec2:VpcId. Try this instead:
statement {
  actions = [
    "ec2:CreateSubnet",
  ]
  resources = ["*"]
  condition {
    test     = "StringEquals"
    variable = "ec2:VpcId"
    values   = ["vpc-xxxx64eeb9480xxxx"]
  }
}


First I tried this only. It was not working so I added StringEqualsIgnoreCase. Thought may be some case sensitivity issue.

Why do you say the one in the question is for S3 bucket policies? I don't see any difference between the one in the question, and the one in this answer, other than StringEqualsIgnoreCase versus StringEquals. Are you saying StringEqualsIgnoreCase can only be used in bucket policies? Because that's clearly not true: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html
